# sort the list by alphabetically with last name, if names are same with book title

Tags: python, list, sorting

Trying to sort with an order of the last name from the list of author names, and books like this. Does anyone know how to get an index value right before the ',' this delimiter? Which are the last names.
I need to put the index value in the lambda x:x[here]
Also what if the author names are the same how do I order them in alphabetical order of book titles?

```
name_list= ["Dan Brown,The Da Vinci Code",
            "Cornelia Funke,Inkheart",
            "H G Wells,The War Of The Worlds",
            "William Goldman,The Princess Bride",
            "Harper Lee,To Kill a Mockingbird",
            "Gary Paulsen,Hatchet",
            "Jodi Picoult,My Sister's Keeper",
            "Philip Pullman,The Golden Compass",
            "J R R Tolkien,The Lord of the Rings",
            "J R R Tolkien,The Hobbit",
            "J.K. Rowling,Harry Potter Series",
            "C S Lewis,The Lion the Witch and the Wardrobe",
            "Louis Sachar,Holes",
            "F. Scott Fitzgerald,The Great Gatsby",
            "Eric Walters,Shattered",
            "John Wyndham,The Chrysalids"]
```

```
def sorting(name):
    last_name =[]
    name_list = book_rec(name)
    
    for i in name_list:
        last_name.append(i.split())
    name_list = []
    
    for i in sorted(last_name, key=lambda x: x[]):
        name_list.append(' '.join(i))
    
    return name_list
```

Comment: "get an index value right before the ',' this delimiter?" I don't understand what you mean. For the exact input you have shown, exactly what output do you want?

Comment: Use a [name parser](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You'll run into trouble with double last names with this approach

Answer (score 1):

`split` on comma, keep first part; `split` on white space, keep last:

```
name_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split()[-1])
```

If you also want to sort by book titles for the same author last name, then maybe it's better to use a function that throws key:

```
def sorting_key(author_title):
    author, title = author_title.split(',')
    # first by author last name, then by book title
    return author.split()[-1], title

name_list.sort(key=sorting_key)
print(name_list)
```

Output:

```
['Dan Brown,The Da Vinci Code',
 'F. Scott Fitzgerald,The Great Gatsby',
 'Cornelia Funke,Inkheart',
 'William Goldman,The Princess Bride',
 'Harper Lee,To Kill a Mockingbird',
 'C S Lewis,The Lion the Witch and the Wardrobe',
 'Gary Paulsen,Hatchet',
 "Jodi Picoult,My Sister's Keeper",
 'Philip Pullman,The Golden Compass',
 'J.K. Rowling,Harry Potter Series',
 'Louis Sachar,Holes',
 'J R R Tolkien,The Hobbit',
 'J R R Tolkien,The Lord of the Rings',
 'Eric Walters,Shattered',
 'H G Wells,The War Of The Worlds',
 'John Wyndham,The Chrysalids']
```

Comment: how do I get the index value of the book titles? If the author is the same I need to sort it by the book name.

Comment: @DongookKim please see the edit. does it work now?

Comment: I'm trying but the sorting_key function is not working for me, is there any way to sort twice the first author name and the book title if the authors are the same?

Comment: @DongookKim what's the expected outcome? Is the list sorted in the way you wanted in my answer? Post your expected outcome and let's see where the problem is

Comment: the expected output is the same as you posted but I made sorting_key function but trying to imply to my code but it doesn't work for me, it's just I'm bad at this.

Comment: Is there any possible way to add that to my sorting(name) function?

Comment: @DongookKim what's `book_rec()` and how are you planning to use this function? It seems to take `name` parameter, what is it? If you insist on using it, we can make it work.